# Application Insights is not yet supported for .NET 5 Web Apps

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, .net-5

I have a .Net 5.0 web app deployed into an Azure App Service web app.

Today, I wanted to enable an Application Insights instance for my app service web app, but looks like it's impossible at the moment due to the `Application Insights is not yet supported for .NET 5 Web Apps` message.

[image]

I don't wanna downgrade to asp.net core 3.1. Do you have any suggestions?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1960

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, the [code-less mode](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2119)(link application insights via azure portal) is not supported.

Before this feature is available, only app-insights SDK based approach can be used there. So as a workaround, you can install the related app-insights package in your project locally, then publish the project to azure.